# Skype continutes to crash with SIGSEGV error (OS X 10.9.5) (Skype 7.2.412)

Tags: macos, crash, skype

I have been waiting for a new version of Skype to come out but I am getting impatient. Skype one day just stopped launching. It will launch with these two windows and then crash with a segmentation error.

[image: Skype Window Restore]
[image: Skype Crash Report]

I have a guess that some software must of updated and did something to a system plugin or library that is causing C++ to have a fit but I can't find any log to prove it.
I have done a full uninstall of Skype including any files found in system or library directories but when I reinstall it some hidden cache, properties, or configuration file allows Skype to remember it crashed which leads me to believe that it is also possible that that hidden file is corrupted. These are the files I deleted:

- /Applications/Skype.app
- /Users/*[USER]*/Library/Application Support/Skype
- /Users/*[USER]*/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/Skype_*[CRASH ID]*.plist *(All Crash Report Files)*
- /Users/*[USER]*/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins/SkypeABDialer.bundle

This is software I installed with Homebrew:

```
bash        ffmpeg      lame        xctool
berkeley-db grails      readline    xvid
faac        groovy      x264
```

I remember installing *Open Broadcast Software* around the time the problem arose.

And finally, [the latest crash report](http://pastebin.com/NCU5nQaa)

Answer (score 1):

This not a answer to your actual problem, but a guide how to completely remove Skype.

Following  are the files and Folders to remove:

[image]

Since you mention it, the Open broadcast install, it could be interfering with Skype, so try removing it to see if it fixes that problem.

Comment: I forgot that I did remove the preference but I will use the uninstaller I suspect you are using to do this to remove these files

Comment: Nope, I used the AppCleaner.app

Comment: It could be a conflict with Facetime and iChat so make sure they are closed down.

Comment: I hope you do not have a Flashback Trojan Horse Variant malware problem. If you have a virus scanner use it.

Comment: I don't have a flashback virus. I have checked multiple different ways.